# Change in the behaviour of zip command on linux

Tags: linux, docker, zip

In the morning (13th June 23), deployment to our production server started to fail. While it was working 3 days back (10th June 23), and there was no change in our build commands or CI.

#### We use (for context about this post)-

- GitLab CI
- `node:lts` docker image (which is v18 at the time of writing)
- We use `zip` command to zip & copy our final build to AWS ElasticBeanstalk.

#### Description

Upon deeper investigation, we found out that the deployment was failing because of a hidden file (not important for this post - `.npmrc`) that was supposed to be in the root folder but was being copied inside another nested folder.

#### Final build folder (to be zipped)

```
customer-app/
├── .npmrc
├── .platform
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── nginx-extend.conf
├── main.js
├── package.json
└── templates
    └── mail
        ├── email-verification.ejs
        └── share-app-credential.ejs
```

Our CI was running the following command-

```
cd customer-app
zip ./customer-app-final.zip -r * .[^.]*
```

#### Before (when the deployment was working fine)

Earlier, this resulted in the following zipped content (after extracting `customer-app-final.zip`)-

```
build-working-2023-06-09_20-01-19-v4/
├── .npmrc
├── .platform
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── nginx-extend.conf
├── main.js
├── package.json
└── templates
    └── mail
        ├── email-verification.ejs
        └── share-app-credential.ejs
```

#### Now (when the deployment started to fail)

```
build-failing-2023-06-13_07-56-03--897971157
├── customer-app
│   ├── .npmrc
│   ├── .platform
│   │   └── nginx
│   │       └── conf.d
│   │           └── nginx-extend.conf
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── package.json
│   └── templates
│       └── mail
│           ├── email-verification.ejs
│           └── share-app-credential.ejs
├── main.js
├── package.json
└── templates
    └── mail
        ├── email-verification.ejs
        └── share-app-credential.ejs
```

#### What went wrong (the difference of the `zip` command)

If you notice, the hidden files and hidden folders were not zipped at the root level; instead, the zip command recursively zipped the parent folder (i.e. `customer-app` where we ran the command itself).

#### How we fixed

We read the manpage of `zip` and did various tests, and we finally changed our CI commands to-

```
cd customer-app
zip ./customer-app-final.zip -r .
```

#### Now, questions

1. Why the earlier zip command failed in CI?
2. Why has it worked fine for the last 2 years?
3. Why the earlier zip command still works on my Mac (macOS Ventura)?
4. What really changed in the `node:lts` Docker (see below for more for Docker image)?

These all boils down to one single question - What really went wrong?

#### About Node Docker image

After spending almost the day in trying to figure out the root cause, I noticed that earlier (when things were working fine) `node:lts` was pulling a different docker image-

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0~beta.5.gf131a6a2 (f131a6a2)
  on green-1.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default JLgUopmM, system ID: s_b9608e9d087b
  feature flags: FF_USE_IMPROVED_URL_MASKING:true
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:19
Using Docker executor with image node:lts ...
Pulling docker image node:lts ...
Using docker image sha256:78b037dbb659142a12986b522897824ab60209d194a336c15a5006a55fffe9b0 for node:lts 
with digest node@sha256:8cdf7234449f35e579f7491137807ddb3a089f028862f7ab69af437cc9f47ff1 ...
```

But I noticed that the image was changed when things started to fail-

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0~beta.5.gf131a6a2 (f131a6a2)
  on green-5.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default xS6Vzpvo, system ID: s_d878f787d8ea
  feature flags: FF_USE_IMPROVED_URL_MASKING:true
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:19
Using Docker executor with image node:lts ...
Pulling docker image node:lts ...
Using docker image sha256:aa392f56f4662693c4506ca65a41072c0b19c35bd653741e5f4398836bd230e1 for node:lts 
with digest node@sha256:d244ade7d0b2ad97002102880142c8b9a4b016ea2308af87e9b150c43987b301 ...
```

The diff can be seen here https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/commit/f6d495ebff10a46ec06cd38b84c1ed4e89ab5490#diff-2d1474314b1d4bd582bd6d27d91b74cfdd66fdeff2e2357c898cd7d1da45347cR25. (checkout `repos/node/remote/lts.md`)

Comment: To me this points at a change in the shell, not in zip. What do you guys *think* `.[^.]*` does? The shell (or zip, as it were) don't understand regex syntax, a negation in globbing would have been `[!`, a caret has no special meaning ... why it ever worked I cannot answer.

Comment: Yeah, tried that @tink. I also got reply from Docker team https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/14822 & https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/pull/1881.